# Find the limit of the following series

Tags: calculus

As n approaches infinity, find the limit of (n/2n+1).

I know if there was a number in place of infinity, I would plug that in for the "n". But what do I do for the infinity sign?

Answer (score 2):

Notice $$ \frac{n}{2n +1} = \frac{1}{2 + \frac{1}{n}} \to \frac{1}{2}$$

Since $\frac{1}{n} \to 0 $

Added: if  we have

$$ \frac{n}{(2n)^3 + 1} = \frac{ \frac{1}{n^3} }{2^3 + \frac{1}{n^3}} \to 0$$

since $\frac{1}{n^3} \to 0 $

Comment: And would this change if the 2n was cubed?

Comment: See the edited answer